# In Windows Store, game size is 1.9GB, but download continues after 2.3GB

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I have a paid internet connection (daily limit: 1GB). To download the game `Modern Combat Versus` from Windows Store, I therefore paused the download a couple of times. Now, when I resume, the download goes on even after already having loaded 2.3GB of data (see screenshot below).

What could be the problem and how can I fix it? Is there any way to fix this problem without deleting the already downloaded data completely?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: increases to 2.6 gb

Comment: i think it's going to download whole Microsoft's database

Comment: now it become 2.7gb

Comment: What build of a Windows 10 update question

Comment: windows 10 pro version 1511 os build 10586.494

Comment: You are not using a supported build of Windows 10.  You need to update to 1607, 1703, or 1709.  1511 support recently ended. Time to update!